# Would a hotel in Turkey question absence of entry stamp in passport?

Tags: hotels, borders, turkey, passport-stamps

I have the passports of countries A and B neither of which require a visa to Turkey (to avoid doubt, none of them is Turkish).

I am planning to book a flight in passport A, present passport B at the immigration and use passport A when checking into a hotel.

What is the likelyhood that the hotel staff will check/question as to why there is no entry stamp in the passport I present to them? Would there be any issues with that?

I understand that it is normally not the hotel's business to worry about that but, in some countries, hotels are legally required to pay attention to foreigners and report to authorities if they suspect something might be wrong with their visas / border entry / allowed stay etc.

Comment: I don't know whether it will be a problem, but the other side of this is that, when you leave Turkey, there will be no reports of where you stayed associated with passport B.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan are such reports even generated? I could have stayed at friends' place.

Comment: Does anything prevent you from using passport B at the hotel (either right away, or in case you're asked about the missing stamp)?

Comment: @ugoren nothing prevents, but I would strongly prefer to use passport A.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you've stated, some countries require hotels to check your visa status when you check-in (eg, China), or require you to provide visa details in order to avoid paying taxes (eg, Israel).  Turkey does NOT require either of these.

I have checked into hotels in Turkey dozens of times, across 10 or more different hotels. On every occasion they have required my passport for identification (and generally taken a copy of the bio page), but they have never looked for or copied the page containing the entry visa, or taken any other action to confirm my legal presence in the country.